# Help needed after Ubuntu 14.04 trial

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows

I wanted to try Ubuntu before I install it on my windows laptop Asus N550. So I downloaded the 14.04LTS version and loaded it on a bootable USB thumb drive. Everything went smoothly and I liked the experience a lot. However once I restarted the laptop to switch to windows I was faced with a blue screen with an error 0xc0000225 saying I cannot access my OS drive. I went back to Ubuntu and it works fine.
The suggested fix is to load the recovery disc but I do not have one - and neither the recovery partition on HDD- since I replaced it long time ago with SSD. I tried using a bootable USB with windows and I tried the available tools but with no success. One thing I noticed is that these tools asked me to select a system which is always win 8.1 which was my original OS before I upgraded to win 10.

Please I need help as this is my primary device and I need it to lunch windows ASAP.

Comment: Did you change any UEFI settings before booting Ubuntu? Also, have you tried googling for the error code? It produces output like [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-7-64-bit-bootmanager-fails-with-status/1f44c456-fe03-4d13-84f1-8d052ef42bda?auth=1). I'll close-vote this as off topic, as it seems to be purely windows-related.

Comment: I didn't change the UEFI settings, but I did use the force boot from USB option otherwise it would fastboot to Windows. The thing is all this happened due to try Ubuntu option that I have used and it seems many others using a dual boot installations have had similar issues. I tried the Boot-Repair tool but it didn't work either.

Comment: And you're right it might be a Windows specific issue but since Windows repair tool can't seem to fix it I thought maybe there is something that Ubuntu trial did that I need to reverse first.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I tinkered more in the windows setup and found the problem(s) preventing successful windows repair tools. 
Anyway it still bothers me that a simple trial of Ubuntu did all this mess. I still want to load Ubuntu on the laptop maybe in a permanent manner next time around.
Cheers.